# Reaping child processes when using fork()

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

I'm trying to reap child processes when using `fork()` to run two commands in parallel. I'm doing this with the following code:

```
int process() {
    int w, status;  
    while ((w = waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG)) > 0)                               
         fprintf(stderr,"Completed: %d (%d)\n",w,status);

    int pid;                                                                
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)                                                 
       errorExit (EXIT_FAILURE);                                           

    if (pid == 0) {                                                         
        // run first command                                            
    } else if (cmdList->right) {                                            
        // run second command                                           
    } 
}
```

My understanding of this code as it is: I run a `waitpid()` continously thorughout the runtime of the program and whenever `waitpid()` returns a value greater than 0, it reports it (thereby allowing the zombie to die) and then executes the `fprintf()` to `stderr`. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: The `while` loop will clean up any dead children before the fork (without waiting if there are no such children).  You may need to do another similar loop in the parent process after the fork too.  It is a little worrying that `w` and `status` are global varables.

Answer (score 1):

This code will make sure that all terminated children are removed, as the flag suggests:

> WNOHANG
>
> The waitpid() function shall not suspend execution of the calling thread if status is not immediately available for one of the child processes specified by pid.

[Ref](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid)

So while you meet these kind of children, you will execute the `fprintf()`. So if you have two of these children, the `fprintf()` will be executed twice. The `fprintf()` will write to `stderr`.

Note that after that loop you do, you call `fork()` again, which will create a child, which is not going to be handled by the loop.